# Limit the string lenght with a defined character number

Tags: c#, string, split

Is there a way of like that: i have a string and it has perhaps 5000 characters, my goal is to split up the string with 100 charachter per a row and produce 50 rows. if you have opinion, could you tell me in c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use a extension method for that:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitByLength(this string str, int maxLength)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < str.Length; index += maxLength)
    {
        yield return str.Substring(index, Math.Min(maxLength, str.Length - index));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a LINQ method to do it:

```
var split =
    text
        .ToCharArray()
        .Select((c, n) => new { c, n })
        .GroupBy(cn => cn.n / 100, cn => cn.c)
        .Select(x => new string(x.ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       string Deneme = "Deneme Deneme Deneme Deneme DenemeDeneme Deneme Deneme Deneme
                        Deneme Deneme Deneme DenemeDeneme ";
        string Sonuc = "";

        while (Deneme.Length > 0)
        {
            Sonuc += new String(Deneme.Take(3).ToArray()) + Environment.NewLine;
            Deneme= Deneme.Remove(0, Deneme.Length >= 3 ? 3 : Deneme.Length);  
        }
```

what do you think about with this LINQ Solution?

Comment: Is this what you have tried? If so, you can merge it with your question via the edit button below the question.

Comment: its not my solution, one of my programmer friends give the solution and it works